# Changing df column name while leaving default columns as a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that look as follows (first on is df):

| Index | Date | Detail | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2001/01/21 | AAA | 1 |
| 1 | 2001/01/22 | BBB | 2 |
| 2 | 2001/01/23 | CCC | 3 |

The second one is df_2:

| Index | 2001/01/24 | DDD | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2001/01/25 | EEE | 5 |
| 1 | 2001/01/26 | FFF | 6 |

The system that I pulled the information out of split the data into 2 separate excel sheets/tabs. However, the information in df_2 was not given any column names as was the info in df. I need to concatenate them, however, if I insert an empty row of information in .loc[0] and then amend this empty info to the correct columns as in df, this will not work as the columns have already been set.

If I try to replace or rename the columns in df_2, this will force me to lose the information in that first column in df_2 which I need.

How would I go about keeping the first row in df_2 while giving it the same column names as those in df in order to concatenate the two dataframes? The result needs to look as so for df_2:

| Index | Date | Detail | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2001/01/24 | DDD | 4 |
| 1 | 2001/01/25 | EEE | 5 |
| 2 | 2001/01/26 | FFF | 6 |

Thereafter, I can simply say:

```
pd.concat([df,df_2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with `set_index`/`reset_index` and `transpose`:

```
(df_2
 .drop(columns='Index')      # drop Index column
 .T.reset_index()            # reset column header
 .set_index(df.columns[1:])  # set names
 .T
 .reset_index(drop=True)     # drop old index
 .rename_axis('Index')       # set new index name 
 .reset_index()              # set new index as column
)
```

output:

```
   Index        Date  Detail  Amount
0      0  2001/01/24     DDD       4
1      1  2001/01/25     EEE       5
2      2  2001/01/26     FFF       6
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try to drop the Index: KeyError: "['Index'] not found in axis". I think I should add that the Index column is not actually a column - it is simply an index. I placed it there just for completeness purposes.

Comment: Thank you - got it to work! The final code is as follows: 
`df_2_transposed = df_2.T.reset_index().set_index(df.columns[0:])`

`df_2_final = df_2_transposed.T.reset_index(drop=True)`